# Analysis of Recursive Algorithms

Tags: analysis, recurrence-relations, recursive-algorithms

So say I'm going to analyze a factorial function:

*pseudocode:*

F(n)
**if** n=0 **return** 1
**else return** f(n-1)*n

This is my basic operation: $F\left(n\:-\:1\right)\cdot n$

now when it comes to the recurrence relation which is:

$M\left(n\right)\:=\:M\left(n\:-\:1\right)\:+\:1$

I don't quite grasp where the $+\ 1$ is coming from or what it means.
My lecture notes say that it means to multiply $F\left(n\:-\:1\right)$ by $n$, but this isn't very clear to me.

Comment: That's correct. In your teacher's model, multiplying two integers together is seen as an $O(1)$ operation.

Comment: It means that the number of operations to calculate F(n) is the number of operations to calculate F(n-1) plus an additional multiplication.

Comment: To elaborate on the above, $M$ is the number of steps (operations). You can see by induction that the number of operations for a number $n + 1$ is 1 more than for a number $n$, hence the plus $1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that $M(n)$ is supposed to represent some formulation of the time it takes to run $F(n)$; in this case, imagine that $M(n) = M(n-1)$ instead of $M(n)$. Then $M(1000) = M(999) = M(998) = $ ... $ = M(0)$ (I'm also assuming that $M(0) = 1$), so the time required to run $M(1000)$ would equal to the time required to run $M(0)$. On the other hand, if $M(n) = M(n-1) + 1$, then $M(1000) = M(999) + 1 = M(998) + 2 = M(997) + 3 =$ ... $= M(0) + 1000$.  Essentially, the +1 is indicating that there is a unit of time spent evaluating a single call of the function, which includes performing the multiplication of $F(n-1) \cdot n$ and evaluation of the if-statement.

Comment: thanks, for the explanation. I was looking at as if M(n) and f(n) represented the same thing.